# Calling methods of Singleton class concurrently

Tags: java, singleton

I have a sinlgeton object which holds one method, which is NOT synchronized. The singleton can be accessed by many clients at a time - what will happen if multiple clients access that object ? 
Actually I want to write a log in a single file using that method.

Comment: Many logging frameworks (e.g. `log4j`) are already designed to be thread safe.  So even if multiple threads are accessing your singleton's method there might not be a problem.

Comment: We can't use external libraries or wrapper for java log

Answer (score 1):

I guess by clients, you mean threads. Assuming you have implemented singleton correctly, all threads would be using the same instance. Since this is a method that changes state (writing to a file), it would require in general require some sort of synchronization. Although it depends on some factors - for example, if your method writes just a single line in a single call to BufferedWriter.write(), it is fine. [Because BufferefWriter.write() does synchronization internally](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/Writer.java#Writer.write%28java.lang.String%29). However, if you write multiple lines or make multiple calls to BufferedWriter.write(), the different calls might execute out of order.

Now, if by clients you mean different processes, simple synchronization of course will not help. You can use [FileLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html) to lock the file if the processes are in the same JVM. Otherwise, you have to lock using something external, such as use another temp file as lock. It depends on the OS though if it provides atomic file creates.

Comment: Thanks. Currently I am going to add synchronized modifier to that method.